Append PowerShell Tables to one table
I am not looking for a Join like an Inner Join, Outer Join, or Left or Right Join as in SQL. I am looking for something more like this:
I have a table 1 that has the following data in PowerShell



Description
Manufacture
Name




Cell 1
Cell 2
Cell 3


Cell 4
Cell 5
Cell 6



Which resulted from this query:
gwmi -Namespace "root\CIMV2 -Class "Win32_PnPEntity" | select Description, Manufacture, Name, | Where Name -Like "*CellContents*"
I have another table that has the following contents that comes from a similar query as well:



Description
Manufacture
Name




Tell 1
Tell 2
Tell 3


Tell 4
Tell 5
Tell 6



Which resulted from this query:
gwmi -Namespace "root\CIMV2 -Class "Win32_PnPEntity" | select Description, Manufacture, Name, | Where Name -Like "*TellContents*"
The final output of the table should be the following:



Description
Manufacture
Name




Cell 1
Cell 2
Cell 3


Cell 4
Cell 5
Cell 6


Tell 1
Tell 2
Tell 3


Tell 4
Tell 5
Tell 6



I have been researching and found a question that with the following content:
In PowerShell Whats the best way to join two tables into one
However, this seems to work with a primary key. I guess that I am looking for a UNION between the values. I have been searching the website for a while now and I keep finding joins that seem to have a primary key, and some that require an external library such as "Join Object".
(gwmi Query1) UNION (gwmi Query2)
The method above did not work.
(gwmi Query1).Append(gwmi Query2)
The method above did not work.


So since both outputs are results from the same class you could just join the filtering expressions with -or:
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\CIMV2 -Class Win32_PnPEntity |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*CellContents*' -or $_.Name -like '*TellContents*' } |
    Select-Object Description, Manufacture, Name

Using WQL, the filter would be something like:
$filter = "Name LIKE '%CellContents%' OR Name LIKE '%TellContents%'"
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\CIMV2 -Class Win32_PnPEntity -Filter $filter |
    Select-Object Description, Manufacture, Name

